# Vaadin: Resizing ComboBox in old Reindeer Theme not possible?

Tags: java, css, combobox, vaadin

im trying to resize an ordinary combobox-element in a Vaadin-UI. My idea was just to change the font-size so that the element resizes itself.

The crappy result looks like that:

[image]

can anybody help?

Comment: Which Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: im using vaadin 7.6.3

Comment: Have you tried something like <yourCombobox>.setWidth("150px"); <yourCombobox>.setHeight("150px");  ? You can also use  <yourCombobox>.setSizeFull(); which will expand you combobox to fill whatever layout it is inside. If there are several elements in this layout you can use  <yourCombobox>.setExpandRatio(1) to give it precedence.

Comment: yeah ...no effects..maybe because the background images of the combobox are png's and not sizeable?

Comment: Are you able to provide a snippet of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With old Reindeer theme it is not possible to change combo box size on easy way because things are fixed in css.

I suggest to migrate your project to Valo theme if it is possible.
In Valo theme you have ValoTheme.COMBOBOX_HUGE style.

Comment: Can you not override the css width with a custom style and a !important tag to change the width/height?

Comment: You can try, but I am not sure that you will be satisfied with the results. Css style use image background and etc. Generaly Reindeer is not simple for extending. That is reason of Valo popularity.